# Collector which returns array

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
strings.stream().map( i->i.toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The code above returns `List`

I want to achieve analog which will return array.

Is it possible without additional `toArray` method invocation?

Comment: _"without additional toArray method invocation"_ Instead of having `.collect(...)`, you have `.toArray(...)`. And its in the doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Stream` class has two `toArray` methods - here is an example [with Stream::toArray(IntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-):

```
String[] array = strings.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Any ideas for a "real" collector that returns an array? Collector<String, ?, List<String>> arrayBackedCollector = Collectors.collectingAndThen(arrayCollector, List::of);

Answer (score 5):

If you really want a collector (for example to use as downstream for `groupingBy`), you can construct it in pretty simple way:

```
Collector<String, ?, String[]> toArrayCollector = 
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                list -> list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
```